# File access in C# Excel-Dna Addin in Office 365 installed from Windows store

Tags: c#, uwp, excel-dna

I have a C# Excel-DNA Addin that functions properly on Office versions from 2010 to 365.

One of the actions the Addin performs is creating/writing to a simple text file located in the %APPDATA% directory that is retrieved 
via `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`.

The path is important, since there is other Windows application on the machine that is reading this file from the same path.

The issue starts here:

1. When calling `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` from an Addin that is running in Excel process it returns path similar to:

   ```
   C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Packages\
   Microsoft.Office.Desktop_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppData
   ```
2. A same call from non packaged app returns

   ```
   C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\
   ```

In my case, it means that these 2 application can not communicate anymore via the file system. (Did not try yet pipes or window messages).

I've read this article:
[Accessing additional locations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations)

It looks like that such behaviour is by design -> the Excel app is running in a "sandbox mode" unless I specify more access capabilities to the app manifest. In this case, I don have any control over the app manifest since it's Excel.

Any ideas? Is there a standard way of communication between UWP apps and other programs running on the same PC?

Comment: Just to clarify:

For #1, you say "from an Addin that is running in Excel process". You mean here specifically when Excel is purchased from the Windows Store?

For #2, I would expect the path returned by Environment.GetFolderPath Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData to end at "Roaming", I think you added "SOMEAPP" by mistake.

Comment: #1 - yes. My xll file is loaded into Excel process purchased from store. #2. I updated the path. In anycase, it's different than I get from regular Windows app and different than I get from non Windows store purchased Excel.

Comment: I meant your #2 (lol) - I was wondering about the first path. So, "SOMEAPP" needs to come off the second one also.

Comment: Heh. Sorry, you are correct.

Comment: No worries. As an aside, I can't resist pointing out that this is yet another example of how Microsoft is making llfe so much more difficult for developers. Like you, I have always assumed that the answer to the question "where is this special folder?" was always the same. Clearly now with UWP it is not. I don't have your case, where effectively you rely on this to do cross application communication, but here is another potential pitfall, for myself (and maybe you). My add-in installer relies on this to choose the add-in path. Yet It may be different inside the add-in. That could be a problem!